Get the highest value of a json key with Ansible
I want to get the highest value of a child key with Ansible and store it in a variable. I'm able to do it with a bash command, which I could easily use with Ansible but I'm sure there is a more Ansible way to do it. Here is what I currently have:
- name: get latest version
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: get latest version
      ansible.builtin.command: curl --silent https://download.checkmk.com/stable_downloads.json | jq -r '.checkmk[].version' | sort -r | head -1

How could I improve this and store it in a variable? Thank you!

You can use the uri module to fetch the remote URL, instead of calling out to curl; you can use the json_query filter to parse the data; and you can use the sort and last filters to get the value you want. Finally, you use the set_fact  module to store the value in a variable:
- name: get latest version
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: get latest version
      uri:
        url: https://download.checkmk.com/stable_downloads.json
      register: version

    - set_fact:
        chkmk_version: "{{ version.json|json_query('checkmk.*.version')|sort|last }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "Latest checkmk version: {{ chkmk_version }}"



Get all attributes version

  chkmk_ver_all: "{{ version.json | json_query('checkmk.*.version') }}"

gives
  chkmk_ver_all:
  - 2.2.0p26
  - 2.1.0p43
  - 2.0.0p39
  - 1.6.0p30
  - 2.3.0p1

Use the filter community.general.version_sort and sort the versions
  chkmk_ver_srt: "{{ version.json | json_query('checkmk.*.version') |
                                    community.general.version_sort  }}"

gives
  chkmk_ver_srt:
  - 1.6.0p30
  - 2.0.0p39
  - 2.1.0p43
  - 2.2.0p26
  - 2.3.0p1

Then, get the last version
  chkmk_version: "{{ version.json | json_query('checkmk.*.version') |
                                    community.general.version_sort  |
                                    last }}"

gives
  chkmk_version: 2.3.0p1


But, in the question, you "want to get the highest value of a child key". Then, get all keys

  chkmk_key_all: "{{ version.json.checkmk.keys()  }}"

gives
  chkmk_key_all:
  - 2.2.0
  - 2.1.0
  - 2.0.0
  - 1.6.0
  - 2.3.0

sort the versions
  chkmk_key_srt: "{{ version.json.checkmk.keys() |
                     community.general.version_sort }}"

gives
  chkmk_key_srt:
  - 1.6.0
  - 2.0.0
  - 2.1.0
  - 2.2.0
  - 2.3.0

and get the last version
  chkmk_version: "{{ version.json.checkmk.keys() |
                     community.general.version_sort |
                     last }}"

gives
  chkmk_version: 2.3.0

